# How does overloading the '->' member access operator work?

Tags: c++, overloading

As far as I understand the -> operator dereferences then accesses the members of a pointer to a class object.

identifier->member is effectively the equivalent to using: (*identifier).member

Consider the following: compiled and tested, functions as expected

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int x{0};
};

class A_Abstraction
{
public:
    A *ptrToA;
    A_Abstraction() : ptrToA{new A} {};a
    A *operator->() { return ptrToA; }
};

int main()
{
    A_Abstraction a;
    a->x = 10;
    std::cout << a->x << '\n';
}
```

In my basic understanding the A_Abstraction::operator->() would resolve to a A*, which would still require both dereferencing and the use of a member access operator. So wouldn't accessing A::x through A_Abstraction::operator->() require something like this:   `a->->x`

Obviously it doesn't and the code compiles and runs as expected. How does the compiler manage this?

Comment: @VolkanÜnal yes it does very much, thank you. Should I delete my post or link that post in an edit?

Comment: [member access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators) _"...If a user-defined operator-> is provided, the operator-> is called again on the value that it returns, recursively, until an operator-> is reached that returns a plain pointer. After that, built-in semantics are applied to that pointer...."_

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it resolves to `A*` and it needs dereferencing. However, that dereferencing is handled by (unary) `operator*()`, not `operator->()`.

As for accessing, while the return type is `A*`, you'll only get that if you call it manually (like `a.operator->()`). If you write `a->x`, that's interpreted as `(*(a.operator->())).x` (extra parentheses added to clarify the precedence). Therefore, you can't write `a->->x`.

Comment: Thank you, however I've closed the post now as my question was effectively answered elsewhere.